# What is happening in this command substitution?

Tags: bash, expansion, command-substitution

I have written the following command substitution and executed in in a bash shell:

```
$(echo echo 1; echo 2; echo 3) #output: 1 2 3
```

Why is the double `echo` required in the first expression, while only single `echo`s are required in the second and third?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with what you've actually asked the shell to do.  That is as follows:

"Echo the result of echo 1; echo 2; echo 3"

Comment: That is what I would expect from `echo $(echo 1; echo 2; echo 3)` but when I read the original I see each expression delimited by `;` which I thought would terminate the first echo. Instead, the first echo *passes over* the `;` which I didn't know was possible...

Comment: each token from space to `;` is considered a subcommand (after the first).  Subshells are weird.

Comment: Noted. I always thought the shell expansion worked kind of like the -e switch in perl, but I guess there is much more to it than that..